# Pyspark: filter dataframe based on list with many conditions

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

Suppose you have a pyspark dataframe `df` with columns `A` and `B`.
Now, you want to filter the dataframe with many conditions.

The conditions are contained in a list of dicts:

```
l = [{'A': 'val1', 'B': 5}, {'A': 'val4', 'B': 2}, ...]
```

The filtering should be done as follows:

```
df.filter(
( (df['A'] == l[0]['A']) & (df['B'] == l[0]['B']) )
&
( (df['A'] == l[1]['A']) & (df['B'] == l[1]['B']) )
&
...
)
```

How can this be done with `l` containing many conditions, i.e. a manual insertion into the filter condition is not practical?

I thought about using separate filter steps, i.e.:

```
for d in l:
    df = df.filter((df['A'] == d['A']) & (df['B'] == d['B']))
```

Is there a shorter or more elegant way of doing this, e.g. similar to using list comprehensions?
In addition, this does not work for ORs (|).

Comment: Filter also accepts a sql like expression, u could create a string from ur dictionary and pass a string in there. Ur method is slow because u r looping over the filter, spark doesn’t work like that

Comment: Thank you, that would certainly be an option.

Can you elaborate, why stacking filters is slow? 
So there is a performance difference in e.g. stacking 4 filters or just including all conditions in one filter?

I thought that these are just definitions due to lazy evaluation, so that this gets optimized, when calling something like count()?

Comment: stacking any transformation like that in a **for** loop breaks the execution **DAG** and disallows spark to continue in the fashion its supposed to

Comment: sort of like, in the for loop, you are restarting the engine every time to do a task, when u could just keep the engine running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use your **`list of dictionaries`** to create a **`sql expression`** and send it to your **`filter all at once`**.

```
l = [{'A': 'val1', 'B': 5}, {'A': 'val4', 'B': 2}]
df.show()

#+----+---+
#|   A|  B|
#+----+---+
#|val1|  5|
#|val1|  1|
#|val1|  3|
#|val4|  2|
#|val1|  4|
#|val1|  1|
#+----+---+

df.filter(' or '.join(["A"+"="+"'"+d['A']+"'"+" and "+"B"+"="+str(d['B']) for d in l])).show()

#+----+---+
#|   A|  B|
#+----+---+
#|val1|  5|
#|val4|  2|
#+----+---+
```

Comment: Any better way of doing this?, only works with string types (e.g. nulls etc will make it return empty same for numbers etc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to be messing with SQL, as that might end up in a big mess (strings need to be surrounded by "", None converted to null, Nan etc)

You want to do something similar to this (myrow is your row, and columns is the set of columns you want to search that row for, if you want all columns = df.columns)
:

```
filtered = df
for col in columns:
    if myrow.asDict()[col] is None:

         filtered = filtered.filter(filtered.__getattr__(col).isNull())
    else:
         filtered = filtered.filter(filtered.__getattr__(col).isin([myrow[col]]))
filtered.show()
```

Note you should add another check for is Nan but this should find the row you want, and preserve type translation between python and spark without you worrying about it (besides Nan and null that is, which are not comparable, 2 things being not a number doesn't mean they are the same)

As per filtering out certain rows which is my use case, things get hairy as all the conditions apply at the same time (not what is happening here), but hope this helps.